# How can I find the file containing a specific class somewhere in my classpath?

Tags: java, classpath

I'm trying to find a single file in classpath. This file is somewhere in one of JARs available in classpath. I'm sure that this task is rather typical. Is there any utility for this?

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically (from a Java program), or by hand (e.g. on the command line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this class](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/SearchclassinclasspathandJarfiles.htm), it looks for class files, but you can easily modify to look for all kind of files.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getReource("name");
```

or

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("name");
```

Combined with IOUtils

```
String text = IOUtils.toString(is);
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```